# vbscript FileSystemObject works locally but not live

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

can anyone tell me what's going on with this (what should be) simple peice of VBscript. It is working locally but as soon as I try it online, it kick out an error as below! Everythings saved in the root!

Any ideas appreciated! I'm starting to pull my hair out!

```
<%
'path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/website/somefile.txt")

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile (server.MapPath("/somefile.txt"), 8, True) 

filetxt.WriteLine("Last Update: ") & Now
filetxt.Close
%>
```

I keep getting the following error...

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied

/locations.asp, line 6

Answer (score 2):

Error description is clear. You need write access to the directory which you want. If you're a hosting customer, you should grant write permission to the IUSR account in your control panel. Usually, username similar to `IUSR_sitename.com`. So If it all gets too confusing, perhaps you should open a ticket in your provider's helpdesk.